# with npm install, how to avoid installing dependencies of dependencies

Tags: webpack, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

here is my package.json . Taken from https://github.com/yigalirani/react_webpack_babel

```
{
  "name": "react_webpack_babel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --hot --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.35.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

When running *npm install*, I get 5,752 files in the node_modules directory. most of them are dependencies of the 13 dev dependencies listed in the package.json

My question is: is there a way to avoid getting all these dependencies of dependencies  so my node_modules will have just 13 files that match mentioned 13 entries?

edit: the 13 files should be webpacked so they dont need to import anything

Comment: That's not how npm (or yarn) works. If the dependencies' dependencies (and so on) don't get downloaded, they can't work. They'd be importing from modules/files that don't exist, and will fail. Some packages use `peerDependencies` which leaves it to you to supply sub-dependencies, but that's an antipattern. You can use the `resolutions` field in package.json to avoid duplicates so you end up with only 1 version of say `react` and `react-dom`.

Comment: The dependencies you require depends on other dependencies to work. They won't work without them. Also I don't think that you can turn off installing sub dependencies. A work around is to change the `package-lock.json` file according to your needs as this is the file that npm creates by reading `package.json` file and then use `package-lock.json` file to install everything.

Comment: the 13 files  can be webpacked so they dont need to import anything